# python regular expression to remove repeated words

Tags: python, regex

I am very new a Python

I want to change sentence if there are repeated words.

**Correct**

- Ex. "this just so so so nice" --> "this is just so nice"
- Ex. "this is just is is" --> "this is just is"

Right now am I using this reg. but it do all so change on letters.
Ex. "My friend and i is happy" --> "My friend and is happy" (it remove the "i" and space) ERROR

```
text = re.sub(r'(\w+)\1', r'\1', text) #remove duplicated words in row
```

How can I do the same change but instead of letters it have to check on words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
text = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)( \1\b)+', r'\1', text) #remove duplicated words in row
```

The `\b` matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.

Answer (score 9):

Non- regex solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> strs = "this is just is is"
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> " ".join([k for k,v in groupby(strs.split())])
'this is just is'
>>> strs = "this just so so so nice" 
>>> " ".join([k for k,v in groupby(strs.split())])
'this just so nice'
```

Comment: +1, And I personally prefer not to use regex, but the OP asked about regex.

Answer (score 0):

- \b: Matches Word Boundaries
- \w: Any word character
- \1: Replaces the matches with the second word found

  ```
    import re


    def Remove_Duplicates(Test_string):
        Pattern = r"\b(\w+)(?:\W\1\b)+"
        return re.sub(Pattern, r"\1", Test_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


    Test_string1 = "Good bye bye world world"
    Test_string2 = "Ram went went to to his home"
    Test_string3 = "Hello hello world world"
    print(Remove_Duplicates(Test_string1))
    print(Remove_Duplicates(Test_string2))
    print(Remove_Duplicates(Test_string3))
  ```

Result:

```
    Good bye world
    Ram went to his home
    Hello world
```